# part b of a operator theory problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

**Problem:**
For any integer number 
$ k \geq 1, $
let 
$T_{k} : L_{2}(\mathbb{R}) \to L_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ 
be the linear and continuous operator defined by
$$T_{k}(u)(x)=u\left(x+\frac{1}{k}\right).$$
Let 
$I$ 
be the identity operator on
$L_{2}(\mathbb{R})$
and let 
$\mathcal{L}(L_{2}(\mathbb{R}); L_{2}(\mathbb{R}))$ 
be the Banach space of bounded linear operators on $L_{2}(\mathbb{R})$
endowed with the norm
$$  \Vert T\Vert_{\mathcal{L}}:=\sup \{ \Vert T\Vert_{L_{2}(\mathbb{R})} :\; u\in L_{2}(\mathbb{R}),\; \Vert u\Vert_{L_{2}(L_{2}(\mathbb{R})}\leq 1 \}. $$
(a) Prove that for each 
$u \in L_{2}(\mathbb{R}) $
it holds true 
$T_{k}(u)\to u$ 
strongly in 
$L_{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

(b) Prove that the sequence of the norms 
$\Vert T_{k}-I\Vert_{\mathcal{L}}$
does $\underline{not}$ converge to 
$0$ as 
$k \to \infty.$

The part (a) is obvious, because 
$$ \left\| u\left(x+\frac{1}{k}\right)-u(x)\right\|\to 0 \ \mbox{ as } k\to \infty, $$
but for the part (b) I have no idea. Would you mind suggesting only hint to me?

Comment: As hint try to find a sequence $(u_k)$ such that $||u_k||_2 = 1$ and $T_k(u_k) - u_k$ does not converge to $0$ in $L_2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $u_k (x) = \frac{\sin(k\pi x)}{x\sqrt{k\pi}}$. $T_k(u_k) = ?$. The principal idea is to find a sequence of functions $(u_k)$ with bounded norm in $L_2$ and $(T(u_k) - u_k)$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: While the OP does ask "only [for] hint to me", a modest elaboration would be helpful to Readers to tell where you expect the "hint" to lead.

Comment: @hardmath I edit my answer to explain what I want

Comment: @Youem Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately, I couldn't handle your hint. 
Firstly, I couldn't prove
$\Vert u_{k}\Vert_{2}=1$ (your suggested $u_{k}$).

Next, I also couldn't prove
$\Vert T_{k}-I\Vert_{\mathcal{L}}$
not to tend to
0.

Comment: First $||u_k||_2^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(k\pi x)}{x\sqrt{k\pi}}\right)^2dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(k\pi x)^2}{x^2k\pi}dx\underbrace{=}_{s = k\pi x} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(s)^2}{s^2}ds < +\infty$ which is also independent of $k$. On the other hand $T_k(u_k)(x) = \frac{\sin(k\pi (x+\frac{1}{k})}{(x+\frac{1}{k})\sqrt{k\pi}} = - \frac{\sin(k\pi (x)}{(x+\frac{1}{k})\sqrt{k\pi}}$ then and with the same idea we can compute  $||T_k(u_k) - u_k||_2$ to show that it does not converge to 0.

Comment: For the computing of $||T_k(u_k) - u_k||_2^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(k\pi x)^2}{k \pi} \left(\frac{2x+\frac{1}{k}}{x(x+ \frac{1}{k})}\right)^2 dx \underbrace{=}_{s = k\pi x} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(s)^2}{s^2}\left(\frac{2s + \pi}{s + \pi}\right)^2 ds > 0$ and independent of $k$.

Comment: I hope this is clear now